# Cassandra clean up data and file handlers for deleted tables

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After I truncated and dropped a table in Cassandra, I still see the sstables on disk plus the lot of open file handler pointing to these. 

What is the proper way to get rid of them?

Is there a possibility without restarting the Cassandra nodes?
We're using Cassandra 3.7.

Comment: When you do a truncate Cassandra will automatically create a snapshot in the snapshot folder. Have you removed all data from there?

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra data does not get removed immediately instead marked as tombstoned. You can run `nodetool repair`to get rid of deleted data.